# Deriving an ERD from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, is there a way to find all dependencies? I can use the object dependencies table to find where a view/table references another table.

But it would be good to know where queries which are not producing views/tables, just select queries, rely on a given table too?

Is that possible?

Comment: you need some other tool like dbt/atlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake does not provide functionality that does this "out of the box". It is theoretically possible, but definitely not trivial, by parsing the statements in the QUERY_HISTORY view. For example...

Using SQL functions: you can identify where tables/views should exist in a SQL statement (after the word FROM, after the phrase LEFT OUTER JOIN, etc) and extract those names

- If the SQL is written using (Oracle-style) lists of tables/views rather than ANSI SQL join syntax, this gets significantly more complicated
- If the SQL isn't written with fully-qualified names then getting the FQN for each table/view (assuming that's what you want) is also more complex

Coding your own solution. There are libraries available (e.g. for Python) that can parse SQL. You could, in theory, write a solution based on these libraries - either in Snowpark or as a standalone solution

There are commercial SQL parsers available but these tend not to be cheap